# char array vs int array in java while printing the base value of array

Tags: java, arrays, println

In java while printing char array it gives null pointer exception but in case of integer array it prints null

```
public class Test {
    char c[];
    int a[];
    //while printing c it gives null pointer exception
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Test().c);
        //  in case of integer it prints null  
        System.out.println(new Test().a);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question

Comment: `println` is overloaded for `char[]`, so it behaves differently.

Comment: please explain in detatils.

Comment: May we suggest that you read the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)?

Comment: This looks to me a perfectly valid question. I don't understand why the downvotes. The javadoc says, "throws null if char[ ] is null". But that's about it. What about `int[]`.

Comment: ok i will prefer first javadoc.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet I reckon the reason for the downvotes is that it wasn't clear what the question was.  All I (and I presume the downvoters) saw was a block of code.

Comment: maybe the fact that the question is not stated as @ASdi commented.... Im just guessing....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ The problem with this question was that, OP did include his question but commented it in the code. Most people probably missed it

Answer (score 3):

As 4Castle suggest, the reason is  that

```
System.out.println(...);
```

is not just 1 method but instead many many different methods taking different parameters

[image]

This is known in java as method overloading

Behind the source code:

**println** is calling **print**

**print** is calling **write**

If `write(..)` is using a `char[]` then a NPE is happening because the code is trying (among others) to get the length of the array which is null referenced

```
 private void write(char buf[]) {
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                ensureOpen();
                textOut.write(buf);
                textOut.flushBuffer();
                charOut.flushBuffer();
                if (autoFlush) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
                        if (buf[i] == '\n')
                            out.flush();
                }
            }
        }
```

On the other hand, printing a `int[]` will be ending up into a calling `println(Object x)` where `String.valueOf` is invoked

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

and as you can see

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

the `valueOf(null)` returns ***null***
:)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested, the reason for the behavior of println in your question, is **different overloaded System.out.println(...) methods are getting called**.

- In case of int[] :- *public void println(Object x)*
- In case of char[] :-  *public void println(char x[])*

Don't want to copy paste from Jdk source code.

1. First method first calls String.valueOf(x), which returns null in
   your case.   Then there is a print(s) method call which print null
   if argument passed is  null.
2. Second method throws NPE, null pointer exception in case passed
   argument is null.